# How Can I deduct Percentage from amount

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a situation where given a Column "TotalDue" and a Percentage(17,5%)Could be anything.I need to deduct the percentage and put results in a table

```
CREATE TABLE #ResultTable (NettAmount money, GrossAmount money)
```

For example sake lets take AdventureWorks database they have a totalDue Column on

```
SELECT TotalDue from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
```

How Can I populate my TemporaryTable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Further to comment below

You may want to use the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO #ResultTable 
            (NettAmount, GrossAmount)
SELECT      (TotalDue * (100 / 117.5)), TotalDue
FROM        Sales.SalesOrderHeader
```

---

I'm not sure if I correctly understood your table structure, but you may want to try something like the following:

```
UPDATE  #ResultTable
SET     NettAmount = GrossAmount * (100 / 117.5)
```

... where if `GrossAmount` is `$117.50`, the `NettAmount` will be set to `$100.00`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.May be my question was not clear enough.
"Given a table Eg Sales.SalesOrderHeader in AdventureWorks" for example 
Get the TotalDue and create another table Eg #ResultTable with 2 Columns NettAmount and GrossAmount.

Comment: @devnet247: Will the `TotalDue` be the `GrossAmount` in the new table?

Comment: yes TotalDue will be GrossAmount in new table.

INSERT INTO [dbo.ResultTable](NettAmount,GrossAmount)
Select ?? 
FROM
Sales.SalesOrder